# Login User into Websphere Portal without password using PUMA

Tags: websphere-portal, puma

I want to use facebook to login into Websphere Portal. I use facebook ID to retrieve LDAP uid, but cannot get password. What API can I use to login to portal without password?

Here is my code:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
PortletServiceHome pumaHomeService = (PortletServiceHome) ctx.lookup("portletservice/com.ibm.portal.um.portletservice.PumaHome");
PumaHome pumaHome = pumaHomeService.getPumaService().getPortletService(PumaHome.class);
PumaLocator pumaLocator = pumaHome.getLocator(request);
List<User> users = locator.findUsersByAttribute("uid", "testUser");
User pumaUser = users.get(0);
// How to login this pumaUser without password?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe here is the establishment of a [trust relationship](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/csec_trust.html) in WebSphere. You can't do this via the PUMA SPI but the process is fairly straightforward.

The high level steps are:

1. Implement a custom [Trust Association Interceptor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/spidocs/com/ibm/wsspi/security/tai/TrustAssociationInterceptor.html) class
2. Register it with WebSphere Application Server
3. In your TAI class, return the uid from your original logic.

There are a few tutorials online. Some are [simple](http://lekkimworld.com/2011/06/08/developing_tais_for_websphere_application_server.html), as it is an easy process if your requirement is to log in via username / uid. Bear in mind - TAIs are very powerful, so be sure to understand and be certain when your TAI chooses to perform its logic.

Hope this helps,

-Scott H