# Websphere Portal 7 Custom Login Portlet

Tags: web-services, authentication, websphere-portal

I want to develop custom form based login portlet because I have to validate the user crendential (username/password) using calling some webservice provided by the customer as he is maintaining the user credential in his side not in the portal side, So that if the webservices returns true then I need to authenticate the user to the Portal and redirect to some specific portal page.

**Note:** based on the customer request, the user's password is not stored in default portal LDAP which means, I can not use the portal Login service.

How can ask the portal to authenticate some user without passing the password in my custom login portlet?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of user storage is it?

Comment: It is LDAP however the user is being added to LDAP using some custom portlet so the password is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the WebSphere Application Server [Trust Association Interceptor](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD002/security/sec_ws_tai.html) mechanism for what (to the portal and appserver) is password-less authentication.

Here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528457/login-user-into-websphere-portal-without-password-using-puma/14547700#14547700) that outlines the steps you'll take. You won't be using WPS mechanisms other than your custom portlet for gathering credentials. The rest uses a common technique in the underlying WebSphere App Server.

Comment: Thank your for your reply, however the Trust Association Interceptor will only depends on some request paramater value to check that if the user has been authenticated by the custom login portlet or not, which will have a security hole from my point of view, as any URL sent to the interceptor with the same request parameter, the interceptor will accept it and then authenticate the user to the portal.

Comment: TAI is a java interface you must implement with custom code. If you prefer, you could handle the same form POST you would have in your portlet.

Comment: Yes I can do that,but how to prevent the back button behavior to submit the same URL (which includes the username& password parameters) again?